# Google Script Slow for users of a domain, but fast for users of another domain

Tags: google-apps-script

We use google scripts and google sheets heavily. Recently we noticed a significant slowness in running our scripts, in particular calls like SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getValues() and getRow() take 2-5 second for each tab in our google sheets, and we have over 50 tabs of data.

We noticed the slowness is for all users in our domain. However, if we login with our gmail accounts and run the script it is super fast, GetValues and GetRow return in milliseconds.

Any ideas what is happening? Is there some throttling of the domain going on? I don't see any alerts or errors anywhere.

Thank you

Comment: You need to contact Google.

Comment: This is not an expected behaviour. You will need to contact [Google support](https://gsuite.google.com/contact/).